# Iphone application with login

Tags: ios, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I make iphone application. I use for root controller tab bar controller. One of my tabs is "My profile". In this tab I want to have two navigation view controllers. First controller should appear when user is not logged in. When user log in it should view second navigation controller. But I don't know how to do this. Can some one give some start point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these links for your help.

[Login Screen](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/create-a-loginscreen-in-iphone/)

[screen switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872533/iphone-sdk-how-to-switch-from-a-login-screen-to-a-navigation-interface)